# Deduct value from database column and from textBox value in C# and after the deduction the value must be stored in new column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014

I need help to deduct value from database column and from textBox value in C# and after the deduction the value must be stored in new column.

The column name that contain value is - "txttopup"

And after updated values must be stored in column name - "txtbalance"

I use SQL Server 2014, I attach code and database snap shot

[image: Please click here to preview database snap shot image]

Code is

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ConString = "Data Source = DESKTOP - JENA\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Project_Smartcard; Integrated Security = True";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    // SqlCommand command;
    // SqlDataReader rd;

    String sql = "Select * from WriteCard";

    try
    {
        // cnn.Open();
        // MessageBox.Show("Connection is active!");
        // sc = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        // rd = sc.ExecuteReader();

        // while (rd.Read())
        // {
        //    // Retrieved.Text = rd.row[6]["amount"].Tostring();
        // }

        // sc.Dispose();
        // cnn.Close();

        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = cnn;
        command.CommandText = "update class set txtbalance = txttopup - " + Convert.ToInt32(totalpayment.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cnn.Close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: We really prefer data to be added as formatted text, not images, as you can see its very hard to see the images, and we can't copy and paste them out for testing.

Comment: You don't need to copy the datas from that image, That is snap shot of my Database and Why I attached that you have to see the column name "txttopup" and "txtbalance"

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code(

Comment: Comment still stands... please don't use images on SO, unless its a graphical question. The easier you make it, the faster you will get an answer.

Comment: Theres a few issues, but most concerning is you're missing a `where` clause in your sql; you may want to add one depending in the `txtcardno` you are dealing with. If this column isnt an identity column thats unique, I would add one.

Comment: @DaleK Ok, This is my first experience in stackoverflow, I will use text only instead of images

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, Can you attach the edited coding here please?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Here is my error, And I also tried to solve the issues with Google help, Still this error message appears
" A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider. SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)  "

Comment: As per the error, the application is not able to connect to the database server. Can you connect to the database server from SQL management studio?

Comment: You might want to remove spaces surrounding `=` in the connection string and also change `DESKTOP - JENA\\SQLEXPRESS` to `DESKTOP-JENA\\SQLEXPRESS` . This is the suggestion based in the connection string you shared in the code.

Comment: enclosed the data source name in single quote `Data Source = 'DESKTOP - JENA\\SQLEXPRESS'`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Yes I could connect, Also use the same database for other functions with different buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you’ve written here is trying to update all the rows because you haven’t specified any conditions (i.e you likely need a where clause).  Also you may consider using command parameters rather than using string concatenation.

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ConString = "Data Source = DESKTOP - JENA\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Project_Smartcard; Integrated Security = True";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    String sql = "Select * from WriteCard";

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = cnn;
        command.CommandText = "update class set txtbalance = txttopup - @txtPopup WHERE bdcardno= @barcode";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPopup", Convert.ToInt32(txtPopup.Text));
        // Somehow you will want to gather the barcode number, either through query or another textbox.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", Convert.ToInt32(txtBarcode.Text));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But I don't know how to code it, Can you edit my code which I posted above and attach me here

Comment: @MichaeID, Thank you for the rivision code, But still one of the error appears llike

Comment: @JenaJacksparrow, the issue is likely with your connection string.  Using MS Sql Management Studio, Visual Studio or a variety of other tools, you can connect to your database using a GUI interface and likely get the precise connection string that you will need to connect to your instance.  This is a different issue than the original question, so you should likely create a new question if you have an issue with connecting to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SqlCommand parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks. Also apply filter to avoid update of all rows.

```cs
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = cnn;
command.CommandText = "update class set txtbalance = txttopup - @txtPopup" +
                      " WHERE bdcardno = @bdcardno";
command.Parameters.Add("@txtPopup", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@txtPopup"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtPopup.Text);
//Arrive at the bdcardno using business logic or get it from user
command.Parameters.Add("@bdcardno", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@bdcardno"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtbdCardNo.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for your coding, I tried  your code, However I got SQL error message  as following

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider. SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Try to enclose the server name in `[]` and try to connect.

Comment: I tried many ways , still that error message appears, Can I contact you via Skype or WhatsApp this is my WhatsApp - 0094778485102

Comment: Dont share your personal details in public forum. put the error in the question and will try to help. Otherwise, we can get into a chat in Stackoverflow itself.

Comment: **I'm a new user of stackoverflow** and I don't have experience and  reputation must 100 for create chat room, Can you help me to create chatroom and solve my issue?